Refute uniform convergence
Does the sequence $g_n(x)=\frac{-nx+x^3(n+1)}{-1+nx}$ converge uniformly on $R_{\geq 0}?$ The pointwise limit is given by $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$ for $x>0$, so the limit is not continuous in $x=0$. I would like to use the fact that the uniform limit of continuous functions has to be continuous itself, which would show that the convergence is only pointwise but not continuous. However, the sequence is not defined at $x=1/n$ and thus not continuous there. Is the reasoning still valid? Of course, one could simply argue via the supremum norm and quickly see that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|g_n-g\|_\infty = \infty,$$
but I'd like to use the argument with a discontinuous pointwise limit.
Thanks!

Since  $g_n$ is not continuous you would need to replace each $g_n$ with a continuous function to achieve your goal.

@ Anne Bauval to make the proposed argument work you need to start with a sequence of continuous functions.

@HelloEveryone Though it doesn't either help to answer your question, note that not only $\lim_{n\to\infty}|g_n-g|\infty = \infty$ but even:$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad\sup{x\ge2}|g_n(x)-g(x)|=\lim_{x\to\infty}(g_n(x)-g(x))=\infty.$$

and also$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad\sup_{x\in[0,2]\setminus{1/n}}|g_n(x)-g(x)|=\lim_{x\to1/n}|g_n(x)-g(x)|=\infty.$$

Customarily, to speak of uniform convergence of a sequence, it's necessary to have a sequence, i.e., to have a single domain $D$ and functions $f_{n}$ on $D$. Here, there is not a single domain. <> That said, if you define $f_{n}$ arbitrarily at $1/n$ to fix the domain issue, you're done because the pointwise limit is locally bounded, while the individual terms are not. <> Can you please edit the question to clarify your intent?

I think this is the kind of argument you are looking for.
Let us consider the domain of the functions $g_n,g$ to be $D:=[0,\infty)\setminus \left\{\tfrac{1}{k}\mid k=1,2,3,\ldots \right\},$ that is $D$ is obtained be starting with the positive real line and removing the points where one of the functions $g_n,n=1,2,3,\ldots$ is discontinuous.
Each $g_n$ is continuous on $D$ and $g_n$ converges pointwise to $g$ on $D$. Since $g$ is discontinuous at one point (namely $x=0$) in $D,$ the convergence cannot be uniform on $D$ (or on any set larger than $D$).
